# Retrieving a child object after a commit on an entity object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Lets say I retrieve an entity object that looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Mother {
    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mother",
               targetEntity = Child.class,
               fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
}
```

When retrieving the above object, I commit the transaction (and close the session associated with the object).  Later on in the code, there is a need to retrieve the children.  If I wanted to keep the fetch type as LAZY, is there a way to use the Mother object and still be able to call getChildren() to retrieve the children?  Or would I have to just bite the bullet and query the children via the key of the Mother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I wanted to keep the fetch type as LAZY, is there a way to use the Mother object and still be able to call getChildren() to retrieve the children?

Not if the `EntityManager` has been closed.

> Or would I have to just bite the bullet and query the children via the key of the Mother?

You could retrieve the children when getting the mother using a FETCH JOIN:

```
SELECT m
FROM Mother m LEFT JOIN FETCH m.children
WHERE m.id = :id
```

Other options include:

- using the *Open Entity Manager in View* pattern (if you are using a webapp)
- using an extended persistence context.

Comment: This 'problem' makes me put a lot of getChildrenFor(Mother m) in my service layer. Feels wrong, but not sure what to do.

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood: Well, it depends on your use case and the design of your app but if you're just adding them to avoid lazy loading problems, you're kinda polluting your business layer.

Comment: Thought so. It's when I need to display it in my GUI (Swing) normally and I don't want to create a transaction in my view model. Maybe I should? :)

Comment: The FETCH JOIN solution is if you expect to always want to retrieve the children of the mother right?  I guess my problem is that if a commit is called and then later there might be an if-statement and 'then' you decide you need to retrieve the children.  I guess then you would just have to query the children in a new transaction anyway.

Comment: @digiarnie It all depends on your "business flow" and I can't be more precise without more details. But yes, a fetch join is useful is you *know* you'll need the association.